# Json file dosen't show up in google chrome

Tags: jquery, json, google-chrome, leaflet

I'm developing a page that shows a Json file via jQuery and Leaflet.

The Flickr side is working fine, but when I try to $.getJSON o, I see an error in Chrome's console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/AppServ/www/PFEleaflet/test%20geojson/lot.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

But when i try to open the .html page in FireFox, the Json file shows up, it work fine.

This is the code I am using:

```
var geoLayer = L.geoJson().addTo(map);
var geoList = L.control.geoJsonList(geoLayer);

geoList.on('item-active', function(e) {
    $('#selection').text(JSON.stringify(e.layer.feature.properties));
})
.addTo(map);

$('#geofile').on('change', function(e) {

    $.getJSON(this.value, function(json) {

        map.removeLayer(geoLayer);

        geoLayer = L.geoJson(json).addTo(map);
        map.fitBounds( geoLayer.getBounds() );

        geoList.reload( geoLayer );
    });
}).trigger('change');
```

Any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest opening this page on a local server instead of using file protocol which will cause problems here and other places. Nodejs serve is great, or Ruby's builtin http server.

Here is a great list. https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255

Comment: I tested it with apache AppServe and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

By default, Chrome doesn't allow any page to access the `file:///` scheme, even if the page is in that scheme as well (on your local machine). You can override this default by adding a parameter to the Google Chrome shortcut like so:

Go to your desktop and make a copy of the Google Chrome shortcut. Right click on the shortcut and click `Properties`. In the properties window, add the following to the target attribute (outside of the quotes):

```
--allow-file-access-from-files
```

This should result in a target attribute that looks something like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Now close any open Google Chrome windows and make sure no `chrome.exe` processes are running. Drag your file over the new shortcut that you just created, and your page should launch and work correctly.

**Note:** I don't recommend changing the original shortcut or making this the default because when this is enabled, any page can access the `file:///` scheme, not just pages on your machine.

Comment: Okey, I'll try it now and see the result. Thanks a lot

Comment: I tried to make it work, but the property target dose not accept the new value even if I add it outside the quotes. this is the message I get: The file "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"--allow-file-access-from-files pecified in the Start in field is invalid . Verify that the file exists and that the path is correct

Comment: Make sure there's a space in between `.exe"` and `--allow`. Without the space, I received the same error message.

Comment: Yeah it's the error, but even i add the space, the start in attribute dosen't change, it still "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe". And the Json file still not showing up!

Comment: That's very odd, as I'm using the same method to test one of my projects and it works fine. Does the shortcut to `"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"` work on its own?